# Find only complete match in join table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, match

I have 3 tables, Pizza, Ingredient, and PizzaIngredients which is a join table between my first two tables.

Pizza

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Margarita |
| 2 | Pepperoni |
| 3 | Vegetarian |

Ingredient

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tomato |
| 2 | Pepperoni |
| 3 | Lettuce |

PizzaIngredients

| pizzaId | ingredientId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

I have a list of ingredients, and I want to list all the pizza I can make with the ingredients I have. To be able to make a pizza, i need to have all its ingredients

If in my list of ingredients I have : `[1]`, I want to return the pizza with id 1 since I can only make the Margarita pizza.
If in my list of ingredients I have : `[1, 3]`, I want to return the pizza with id 1 and 3 since I can potentially make the Margarita or the Vegetarian.

What I've tried :

```sql
SELECT
  pi.pizzaId
FROM
  pizzaIngredients pi
WHERE
  pi.ingredientsId NOT IN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT pi2.ingredientsId
    FROM
      pizzaIngredients pi2
    WHERE
      pi2.ingredientsId NOT IN ('1')
  )
```

But It also returns me pizza 2 and 3 which I dont want since I don't have all the ingredients. I use a postgresql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT pi.pizzaId
  FROM pizzaIngredients pi
 GROUP BY pi.pizzaId
HAVING array_agg(ingredientId) <@ array [1,3]
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DMyjfftQ)

Comment: Thanks Edouard, that's the result I wanted. I plan to translate it into my code using TypeORM which is very bad as handling postgresql functions and I don't want to use raw queries. Do you have any idea of how, or if it is even possibe, I can have the same result as your query but without using postgresql functions ? If not, I will approve your answer

Comment: Hi Loic, no idea about TypeORM, sorry

Comment: Oh no worries, I'll handle the TypeORM part ! Was just wondering if you have an idea of a sql query without postgres functions to achieve the same result